# where to specify the root directory of hadoop on slave node?

Tags: configuration, hadoop

I need to setup a `hadoop/hdfs` cluster with one `namenode` and two `datanode`s. I am aware of `conf/slaves` file which lists the machines datanodes are running. But how can I specify where `hadoop/hdfs` is locally installed on slave node? Also the user account to start `hdfs` there?

Edit: in log files, I find following error, when I tried to `start-dfs.sh`

> ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: file:///

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user is expected to be the same as on the master node. The location of the actual data can be modified by changing the `dfs.data.dir` node in`hadoop-site.xml`.

Comment: thanks for the comments, what I am asking is on the place where ``hadoop`` is installed, not the data file should be stored.

Comment: you can specify the HADOOP_HOME env. variable

Comment: it warns with ``$HADOOP_HOME is deprecated``, also it not works, with the same error msg. I am using ``hadoop 1.0.3``

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html says: "The root of the distribution is referred to as HADOOP_HOME. All machines in the cluster usually have the same HADOOP_HOME path."

I was able to set up the cluster environment this way (version 1.0.3)